# Expo Vector Icon - how to change background color?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, jsx

I am using [Expo vector Icon](https://docs.expo.io/guides/icons/#properties) in my app with React Native. I'm using icons as below and it works fine for all the props. However, I've been trying to change the background color and it doesn't change as expected. I've checked the docs and all the properties work as expected except for `backgroundColor`. Any idea why it isn't working?

```
 <AntDesign
       name={name}
       size={size}
       color={color}
       iconStyle={iconStyle}
       backgroundColor="red"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector icon itself doesn't support the background property.

You are referring to the Button, if you want to use the Button you will have to do like below

```
 <AntDesign.Button
       name={name}
       size={size}
       color={color}
       iconStyle={iconStyle}
       backgroundColor="red"/>
```

But if your requirement is only icon, you can simply style it

```
<AntDesign
       name={name}
       size={size}
       color={color}
       style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}/>
```